# Return similar character of two strings in R

Tags: r, string, dataframe

I have the following dataframe called df (`dput` below):

```
  string1 string2
1     bDe     lDC
2      gj      iE
3     Plm     DOl
4    QWVe    dVtQ
```

I would like to return the similar character(s) of the columns string1 and string2. If there are multiple similar character, it should return them all. The desired output should look like this:

```
  string1 string2 similar
1     bDe     lDC       D
2      gj      iE    <NA>
3     Plm     DOl       l
4    qWVe    dVtq      Vq
```

So I was wondering if anyone knows how to return similar characters of strings in R?

---

`dput` of df:

```
df <- structure(list(string1 = c("bDe", "gj", "Plm", "QWVe"), string2 = c("lDC", 
"iE", "DOl", "dVtQ")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to use `str_extract_all()` and use the second string as a regex pattern:

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df %>%
  mutate(similar = map_chr(str_extract_all(string1, sprintf("[%s]", string2)), str_flatten)) 

  string1 string2 similar
1     bDe     lDC       D
2      gj      iE        
3     Plm     DOl       l
4    QWVe    dVtQ      QV
```

Answer (score 2):

A second option would be to use `strsplit` and `intersect`:

```r
library(dplyr, warn=FALSE)
library(purrr)

df |> 
  mutate(similar = purrr::map2_chr(
    strsplit(string1, split = ""), 
    strsplit(string2, split = ""), 
    ~ paste(intersect(.x, .y), collapse = "")))
#>   string1 string2 similar
#> 1     bDe     lDC       D
#> 2      gj      iE        
#> 3     Plm     DOl       l
#> 4    QWVe    dVtQ      QV
```